# Pass variable value from aspx page using JavaScript, to VB.net page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am working on an existing project and have been asked to provide some new functionality. I am new to VB.net.

I have the following HTML table created on an aspx page:

```
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" id="DataGrid1" >

    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table id="pageviews" class="display">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    User ID
                </th>
                <th>
                    Page Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Page Views
                </th>
            </tr>    
            </thead>        
    </HeaderTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate >
            <tr>
                <td onclick="fnGetID(id)" id="<%#Eval("page_name") %>|<%#Eval("user_id") %>">
                    <%#Eval("user_id") %>
                </td>
                <td onclick="fnGetID(id)" id="<%#Eval("page_name") %>|<%#Eval("user_id") %>">
                    <%#Eval("page_name")%>
                </td>
                <td onclick="fnGetID(id)" id="<%#Eval("page_name") %>|<%#Eval("user_id") %>">
                    <%#Eval("Count") %>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate >
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This table is populated by a VB.net call to the database. I am setting the id of  each row of the table as 'username and page name' for the row.

The table displays a username, page name and number of times a user has visited that particular page.

I want the user to be able to click on a row of the table, and go through to the next page with a new table.

The new table will display the dates and times that the user visited that particular page.

In order to do this, the next page will make a call to the database, and will need to know the username and the page name.

I have a JavaScript onClick method, which will display the username and page name in alert box, separated by a pipe. The method is below:

```
    function fnGetID(pUserID) {
        alert(pUserID);
        window.location.href = 'IndividualView.aspx'
    }
```

Currently this onClick will also direct the user to the next page, where the new table will be displayed, as above.

My problem is, how do I pass the variable to the next page, it has to end up in the VB.net code, so it can be included in the query.

I have tried:

```
window.location.href = 'IndividualView.aspx?field1=UserID'
```

But this will not pass the variable, but the actual text 'UserID'.

Even if this did work, how would I then get it from the JavaScript to the VB page.

I have searched but there is no clear solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `UserID` is a variable

*Use*

```
window.location.href = 'IndividualView.aspx?field1=' + UserID;
```

In VB.NET you need to use [HttpRequest.QueryString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) property

```
Dim field1 As String = Request.QueryString("field1")
```